# How to write this regex expression

Tags: regex

In my HTML I have below tags:

```
<img src="../images/img.jpg" alt="sometext"/>
```

Using regex expression I want to remove `alt=""`

How would I write this?

**Update**

Its on movable type. I have to write it a like so:(textA is replaced by textB)

```
regex_replace="textA","textB"
```

Comment: [You can't parse XHTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Movable Type try this:

```
regex_replace="/alt=""/",""
```

http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/developer/passing-multiple-parameters-into-a-tag-modifier.html

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just find 'alt=""' and replace it with ' ' ?

Answer (score 1):

What regex you are asking for ? Straight away remove ..

```
 $ sed 's/alt=""//'
    <img src="../images/img.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="../images/img.jpg" />
```

This does not requires a regex.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression matches `alt="sometext"`

```
alt=".*?"
```

Note that if you used `alt=".*"` instead, and you had `<img alt="sometext src="../images/img.jpg">` then you would match the whole string `alt="sometext src="../images/img.jpg"` (from `alt="` to the last `"`).

The `.*` means: Match as much as you can.

The `.*?` means: Match as little as you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/ alt="[^"]*"//
```

Answer (score 0):

This `regex_replace` modifier should match any IMG tag with an `alt` attribute and capture everything *preceding* the `alt` attribute in group #1.  The matched text is then replaced with the contents of group #1, effectively stripping off the `alt` attribute.

```
regex_replace='/(<img(?:\s+(?!alt\b)\w+="[^"]*")*)\s+alt="[^"]*"/g','$1'
```

Is that what you're looking for?